# NetworkOnMainThreadException exception on one activity only

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I added a new activity and made it the main activity. The previous main activity, along with other activities, accessed data from web sites. Everthing worked fine. The new main activity also needed to access data from a web site, but this time I received a NetworkOnMainThreadException exception. I implemented AsyncTask on the new activity and it now works. I am in the process of implementing AsyncTask on the other activities even though they still work and don't throw the exception. I have read that this is best practice.

Below is the code I use to pull data from a web site. Why does it only throw the NetworkOnMainThreadException excpetion on the new main activity and not on any other activity?

Greg

```
protected String GetNewData(String URLIn) {
    String ThisData = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLIn);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        RetrieveSiteData ThisSite = new RetrieveSiteData();

        ThisData = ThisSite.readStream(con.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ThisData;
}
```

Stack trace

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1236)
 java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:388)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
 com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
com.windsweptsoftware.wslistit.Utilities.GetNewData(Utilities.java:45)
com.windsweptsoftware.wslistit.LogIn.onLoginClicked(LogIn.java:96)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3860)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18673)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Original code that still works in most activities without AsynTask.

```
protected String GetNewData(String URLIn) {
    String ThisData = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLIn);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        RetrieveSiteData ThisSite = new RetrieveSiteData();

        ThisData = ThisSite.readStream(con.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ThisData;
}
```

Comment: "Why does it only throw the NetworkOnMainThreadException excpetion on the new main activity and not on any other activity?" -- since we do not have the stack trace, nor the source code to any of the activities, how are we supposed to help you? If you run that code on the main application thread, you will get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: I added the stack trace. Let me know what else you need to see. How do i determine what the "main application thread" is? I have a main activity and then intents that load other activities. All worked without AsycTask except the new one. I even added another activity that was not the main and that also worked without AsyncTask.

Comment: "How do i determine what the "main application thread" is?" -- if Android is calling into your code, and you are not told otherwise, it is most likely being called on the main application thread. Your stack trace appears to be triggered by `onClick()` on a widget, such as a button -- `onClick()` is being called on the main application thread. You can learn more about the main application thread (a.k.a., "UI thread') in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).

Comment: Yes, I call GetNewData() in several places without AsyncTask from both buttons and listview setOnItemClickListener(). All work.

Comment: Also in onCreate( in several activities. the new activity threw the exception in  a button.

Comment: "All work" -- they shouldn't. And, even if you are not getting the exception (e.g., you changed the `StrictMode` configuration to prevent it), you still need to get that code off of the main application thread, as you are freezing your UI while the network I/O is going on. Always do network I/O (and most disk I/O) in a background thread, whether it is an `AsyncTask` or something else.

Comment: ""All work" -- they shouldn't" This is what is so confusing. They shouldn't, but they do. All work except on the one. If the UI freezes it is very minor. These are not whole web pages I am pulling down. I have pages that feed data to populate lists and such. I'm in the process of replacing all of the direct calls with AsyncTask.